# RegEx to Capture All Text Before String NOT using a Lookahead for Google Apps Script

Tags: regex, google-apps-script

Since I cannot use a positive lookahead in Google Apps Script, I need to find another way to write a Regular Expression. The regex with a positive lookahead looks like this:

```
.+?(?=\nConstant Phrase)
```

I want to capture all the text before the "Constant Phrase" (not including "Constant Phrase"), on any line to the beginning of the google document. I would like the entire regex match to be the text before Constant Phrase as I am not sure how I would reference a matching group in Google Apps Script for Google Docs. Any ideas on how I can accomplish this with a method that will work in Google Docs? Thanks!

**Text in the Google Doc is:**

```
Title of the Page Goes Here
National Recommendation
....rest of document
```

I want to match (in this case) `"Title of the Page Goes Here"`.

Another example as seen in the Regex Tester for Golang. I want the **entire** match to just be `<headline>` or whatever text might be in its place.

[image]

Comment: Can you provide some sample lines? Why doesn't `^(.*?)Constant Phrase` work?

Comment: It works fine in perl and such, but lookaheads are not supported in Google Apps Script.

Comment: I didn't use a lookahead in the above regex.

Comment: Ah, sorry. That includes the "Constant Phrase". I need to match everything before that but NOT including that.

Comment: Use the capturing group, `$1` contains everything before `Constant Phrase`. Ah, does Google Docs not have capturing groups? Maybe I'm ignorant of the environment you're working in. Apologies.

Comment: Ah, I see what you are saying. Guess I am not sure how I would reference the first capturing group. The line of code I am using to reference that regex is: `document.replaceText(regExpUpdateHeadline, newHeadline.getResponseText());`. Not sure how to change that to reference the first group.

Comment: If you post your sample text, I'll fire up a Google Doc and take a look. Or, better yet, share a copy of the doc I can take a look at--I'm OK with regex but haven't used them in docs before.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/197634/discussion-between-ggorlen-and-hunter21188).

Comment: `var lines = s.split("\n"); Logger.log(lines[0]);`? Or, `var m = s.match(/(.*?)\nNational Recommendation/); if (m) { Logger.log(m[1]); }` (where `s` is the string content)?

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew I am looking for the entire match to be the text before the Constant Phrase as I am not sure how I would be able to reference a capturing group in Google Apps Script.

Comment: I have shown it in the comment above. However, `replaceText` might work in a different way. You need to explain what you are doing rather than ask for something that your platform does not support.

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew Ok. I think where I am confused is the string content `s` is unknown. It can be anything. Using either of those methods would I have to know what the string content is? Sorry if it is something simple I am overlooking. I don't use regex much. Thanks!

Comment: `You need to explain what you are doing` Show your current code. Show screenshots. Show 2 to 3 examples.

Comment: Regex only works on strings. What is yours I have no idea, you are hiding the code.

Comment: I have added a screenshot from the Regex Tester. There you can see exactly what I want the entire match to be since referencing matches is not possible in Google Docs from what I have read. I'm not sure what else I can show as an example. That is the only code I have/need is the regex code.

Comment: Forget the regex. Show your GAS code, where you're trying to use regex. Show your document. What purpose does the regexTester screenshot serve? Regex in Google docs isn't the same as everything else. For starters, if you're using `doc.replaceText(regex,text)` it  uses inbuilt regex and only tests only one per line,i.e., you can't reference two lines or use `\n`.. it also uses ``re2`` regex engine. Alternatively, You can get the whole text as string using `body.getText()` and use the JavaScript ES5 regex engine....  I could go on. But without your GAS code and document, it's pointless.

Comment: Ok. I didn't understand really why you needed it, but that helps. Here is a link to an example script and how I would call the regex: https://docs.google.com/document/d/12jmvgizg_Xu-KbLIdPtiZOXlQs-KmWfSoOyIp7xiln8/edit?usp=sharing

Comment: And what are you doing with this document? Extracting text or replacing or removing? What do you expect?

Comment: No, there is no way to match up to `(?=\nConstant Phrase)` without including it in the match `\nConstant Phrase` or using an assertion. There, I said it, I suggest you give up google and its crappy crap...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> would like the entire regex match to be the text before Constant Phrase as I am not sure how I would reference a matching group in Google Apps Script for Google Docs.

[RegExp.prototype.exec](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/RegExp/exec) returns an array of capture groups.  By placing parentheses around the part you wish to match before the constant phrase, you can pluck them out of the returned array and ignore the rest.  Use `\s` to match all whitespace, including the newlines.

```js
function myFunction() {
  var text = DocumentApp.getActiveDocument().getBody().getText();
  var match = /(.*)\s+National Recommendation/.exec(text)[1];
  Logger.log(match); // => "Title will go here...could be anything"
}
```